# Can't create a new image in mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have a long list of images which I'd like to load into a `Tkinter` canvas.

I find that this works if I create my `PIL.PhotoImage` instances before calling `mainloop` on my Tkinter instance. I put the following in a callback function which is bound to a keypress or similar event:

```py
def onkeypress( event )
  canvas.itemconfig( canvas_image, image_content )

image_content = PIL.PhotoImage( file="myfile.jpg" )
mytk.bind( "<Key>", onkeypress )
mytk.mainloop()
```

...But that requires that I load my entire image library into memory before starting the main loop. If I try to create each `PIL.PhotoImage` only as I need it:

```py
def onkeypress( event )
  image_content = PIL.PhotoImage( file="myfile.jpg" )
  canvas.itemconfig( canvas_image, image_content )

mytk.bind( "<Key>", onkeypress )
mytk.mainloop()
```

Then the code executes without giving me an error, but I don't see the canvas content change.

What do I need to do to get the canvas content to change please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because `tk` won't hold the reference of that image object, so GC will collect it after function scope as `image_content` is the last reference and it disappears.

You can easily solve this problem by whatever a long-live reference.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I can see it a function after the `mainloop()` You cannot run anything after the mainloop until the tkinter instance has been closed. So you will need to moved your function into the mainloop and above the binding. Another important issue is your local variable in your function. Your function creates a local image that will be gone once the function finishes so you need to define `image_content` as global in the function.

The same rules apply when working with the canvas as well so if you take my below example you can apply it to your needs as well.

Here is a simple example of how you can save your  reference too an image and apply them any time you need to with buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk


root = tk.Tk()

def change_color(img_path):
    global current_image
    current_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=img_path)
    lbl.config(image=current_image)


current_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="red.gif")
lbl = tk.Label(root, image=current_image)
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

tk.Button(root, text="RED", command=lambda: change_color("red.gif")).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(root, text="BLUE", command=lambda: change_color("blue.gif")).grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Button(root, text="GREEN", command=lambda: change_color("green.gif")).grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image][image][image]